# Jquery auto select option from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#country").load("country.php");
    $("#state").load("state.php");

    $("#country").change(function(){

            switch($("#country").val()){
                case "aus":$("#state").load("aus_state.php");break
                case "eng":$("#state").load("eng_countie.php");break
                case "usa":$("#state").load("us_state.php");break
            }
        });
});
```

I have a dynamic select option, country->state, use jquery load files. However I need to auto select the option from DB. ex. if user's DB's country is usa, than the option will auto select usa.

something like this

```
$country=$data['country'];//query from DB

if($("#country").val()==<?PHP echo $country;?>){select the option...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
</head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //load countries
    $("#country").load("country.php");

    //print php variable into js
    var country = '<?php echo $data["country"]; ?>';

    //set the item that matches country variable as selected
    $("#country option").filter(function() { return $(this).text() == country; }).prop("selected", true);

});
</script>
<body>
(..)
```

Comment: @user2178521 are you getting country value at javascript side or what did you got?

Comment: var country = '<?php echo "usa'; ?>'; i try this and it still not selected